# httpd Reverseproxy to serve all files in html pages served

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf, haproxy

I have successfully (as far as I can tell) created an httpd reverse proxy from an internet facing server to another non-internet facing server. I also created a routing table using haproxy to route specific requests to specific other servers on specific ports. Let's call them servers A, B, and C respectively where C denotes the list of servers and ports being routed to.

Due to our server architecture, this is the only pathway that will be able to serve data to the internet on the intended server.

When I visit the site at https serverA.com/jira I am having A send to B with http serverB/jira which routes based off of /jira to the server in C hosting our internal jira instance at http serverC:somePort

I am getting a page back from jira but it is unformatted and mentions that the page is a broken link. Heading into Firefox's debugger I see in the network tab that the page jira returned with a 404 error but then several other GET's are placed due to the content of the HTML page received and they all get 404'd which makes sense why the page is unformatted.

My main question is this: The httpd is using a Location block based off of /jira however when the additional GET requests are sent, they are sent to https serverA.com/additionalFiles.(css, js, etc.) for which the server will not reverse proxy correctly. Is there a way to either change all requests in the incoming html page to be jira/additionFiles instead of additionalFiles OR have the httpd service to continue serving the reverse proxy for the remainder of the dependencies (I know http is connectionless)? If not, what would be best practice?

My second question which goes along with the first, why am I seeing the 404 in the initial page load and how would I change it to a 200?

Answer (score 0):

Our solution was to use stunnel on the front end server instead and route all https traffic to server B which then hands out the the distributions of where the traffic is supposed to go. I am using servers C and having them use server A as a proxy so all the data is being served correctly and server B is just a middle man.